# How to match the same number of different atoms in Perl 6 regex?

Tags: raku

Should be very simple, but I can't cope with it.

I want to match exactly the same number of `a`s as `b`s. So, the following

```perl6
my $input = 'aaabbbb';
$input ~~ m:ex/ ... /;
```

should produce:

```perl6
aaabbb
aabb
ab
```

**UPD:** The following variants don't work, perhaps because of the `:ex` bug , mentioned in [@smls's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47423958/7730888) (but more likely because I made some mistakes?):

```perl6
> my $input = "aaabbbb";
> .put for $input ~~ m:ex/ (a) * (b) * <?{ +$0 == +$1 }> /;
Nil
> .put for $input ~~ m:ex/ (a) + (b) + <?{+$0 == +$1}> /;
Nil
```

This one, with `:ov` and `?`, works:

```perl6
> my $input = "aaabbbb";
> .put for $input ~~ m:ov/ (a)+ (b)+? <?{+$0 == +$1}> /;
aaabbb
aabb
ab
```

**UPD2:** The following solution works with `:ex` as well, but I had to do it without `<?...>` assertion.

```perl6
> $input = 'aaabbbb'
> $input ~~ m:ex/ (a) + (b) + { put $/ if +$0 == +$1 } /;
aaabbb
aabb
ab
```

Comment: May I ask you what you are doing? I mean, in general. All these regex questions...

Comment: @Holli Do you mean it's too stupid?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky No, she's curious. Besides, most of these questions will be useful to other people in the future. The ones about pre-compiling regexes and regex interpolation have been useful to me.

Comment: Thanks, piojo!  @Holli one of my main tasks is searching, analyzing and transforming large textual corpora, written in different languages. Two years ago I discovered bash utilities (grep, sed and, later, awk) , and two months ago I discovered p6, which helps me a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```perl6
my $input = "aaabbbb";
say .Str for $input ~~ m:ov/ (a)+  b ** {+$0} /;
```

Output:

```
aaabbb
aabb
ab
```

It's supposed to work with `:ex` instead of `:ov`, too - but [Rakudo bug #130711](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130711) currently prevents that.

Comment: Great, thank you! I tried to do something like this, but it didn't work: `"aaabbbb" ~~ m:ex/ (a) * (b) * <?{ +$0 == +$1 }>`

Comment: And the following doesn't work either. Is it because of the `:ex` bug? `say .Str for $input ~~ m:ex/ (a)+  (b)+ <?{+$0 == +$1}> /;`

Comment: I can get it using `:ov` and the 'non-greedy' `?` on the second part: `say .Str for $input ~~ m:ov/ (a)+  (b)+? <?{+$0 == +$1}> /;`

Comment: I've added a working solution with `:ex` to the post (**UPD2**).

Comment: try this one `m:ex/ (a+) (b+) <?{ $0.chars == $1.chars }> /`

Answer (score 5):

```pl
my $input = "aaabbbb";
say .Str for $input ~~ m:ov/ a <~~>?  b  /;
```

Works with `ex` too

```pl
my $input = "aaabbbb";
say .Str for $input ~~ m:ex/ a <~~>?  b  /;
```

### Upd: explanation

`<~~>` means call myself recursively see [Extensible metasyntax](http://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Extensible_metasyntax_(%3C...%3E)). (It is not yet fully implemented.)

Following (longer, but maybe clearer) example works too:

```pl
  my $input = "aaabbbb";
  my token anbn { a <&anbn>? b} 
  say .Str for $input ~~ m:ex/ <&anbn> /;
```